# How to search the correct way in .NET enums

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I want to give my "User"-objects some permissions. That permissions are defined in an enum.
To make it easier to understand, I'll post my code.

```
public  class User
{
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public UserRights Permissions { get; set; }

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return "Username: " + UserName + " - Password: " + Password + " - Permisssions: " + Permissions;
   }
}

public enum UserRights
{
    Admin,
    SmallAdmin,
    SimpleUser,
    JustDummy
}

public class EnumFinder
{
    public List<User> Users = new List<User>();

    public EnumFinder()
    {
        CreateUsers();

        List<User> search = (from a in Users where a.Permissions == UserRights.SimpleUser select a).ToList<User>();
        foreach (User user in search)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.ToString());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Create some example users and put the objects into User's list
    /// </summary>
    private void CreateUsers()
    {
        var user1 = new User();
        user1.UserName = "user1";
        user1.Password = "password1";
        user1.Permissions = UserRights.Admin;

        var user2 = new User();
        user2.UserName = "user2";
        user2.Password = "password2";
        user2.Permissions = UserRights.SmallAdmin | UserRights.JustDummy;

        var user3 = new User();
        user3.UserName = "user3";
        user3.Password = "password3";
        user3.Permissions = UserRights.SimpleUser;
        Users.Add(user1);
        Users.Add(user2);
        Users.Add(user3);
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, I added some example users to my User's list. Each of them has different permissions. Now lets say I want to search for every user which das "Admin" permission. 
This works fine (for that one user):

```
List<User> search = (from a in Users where a.Permissions == UserRights.Admin select a).ToList<User>();
```

But lets say I am looking for a user which has the SmallAdmin permission. So I tried this:

```
    List<User> search = (from a in Users where a.Permissions == UserRights.SmallAdmin select a).ToList<User>();
```

In this case, no user is found. Why not? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you set the right enum value when you added the user with `SmallAdminselect` permission...?

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean, but I corrected a little typo in my example code (missing space..). Can you give me some more details?

Answer (score 4):

Mark your enum with `[Flags]` attribute and use [`HasFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead

```
List<User> search = (from a in Users 
                     where a.Permissions.HasFlag(UserRights.SmallAdmin)
                     select a).ToList<User>();
```

Comment: Oh cool, this can be done automatically? I always assumed I had to manually set the values for each flag like in my answer.

Comment: WOW, this works fine. But.. let's say I want to look for all users, which have permissions "JustDummy" OR "SmallAdmin" OR "Admin". In my eyes this would look like this:
List<User> search = (from a in Users where a.Permissions.HasFlag(UserRights.JustDummy | UserRights.SmallAdmin | UserRights.Admin) select a).ToList<User>();
But only "User2" was found then, not User1 (which has Admin permission).

Comment: I tried using different operators but nothing works. Has anyone another idea?

Comment: @CodeCannibal here is an easy way to do it: `where new [] { UserRights.JustDummy, UserRights.SmallAdmin, UserRights.Admin }.Any(x => a.Permissions.HasFlag(x))`

Comment: Sorry - but I don't think that's correct. If I try this " List<User> search = (from a in Users where new [] { UserRights.JustDummy,  UserRights.Admin }.Any(x => a.Permissions.HasFlag(x)) select a).ToList<User>();" 
then all 3 users will be found. 'User3' has only SimpleUser permission, so it should not be in the results - but it is :)

Comment: I just checked and it's vital that you also adjust the enum's values to what I wrote in my answer. The `Flags` attribute won't do that for you and you'll get the default values 0,1,2,3,...  which won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You use your enums as flags, as can be seen from `UserRights.SmallAdmin | UserRights.JustDummy`.

When doing so you have to use the `[Flags]` attribute for the enum **and** also make sure that or'ing the enum values actually produces meaningful results.

If you change your enum to

```
[Flags]
public enum UserRights
{
    Admin = 1,
    SmallAdmin = 2,
    SimpleUser = 4,
    JustDummy = 8
}
```

then you're already half-way at `UserRights.SmallAdmin | UserRights.JustDummy` will be equal to `10` which is unique to that combination of flags.

In order to test it you have to use the binary and: `(value & UserRights.SmallAdmin) == UserRights.SmallAdmin` for instance will return whether or not this particular flag was set.

---

Actually @Selman22's is better, but this shows how it's handled internally.